# How to parcelable class with own objects and enums

Tags: android, parcelable

I have class tariff and i need to parcelable it.

```
public class Tariff implements Parcelable{

private String operator;
private Discounts discount;
private boolean unlimited;
private Billings billing;
private String name;
private double price;
private double calculated;
private Call call;
private Sms sms;
```

I found some advices here but im not sure i´m getting them right.
1) For parcelable enum I found this. Will that parcelable all values of my enum? Or how should i do that?

```
  try {
        type = Discounts.valueOf(in.readString());
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException x) {
        type = null;
    }
```

2) For parcelable another object(for example call) i found this: If the CategoryDate class is one of yours, you can make it Parcelable as well. Then in your class' writeToParcel() call you can call this.date.writeToParcel() and pass it the same Parcel object. This will cause the CategoryDate class to write its data into the same Parcel object which is being used by CloseItPending.
But i´m not sure i got it right. How exactly should i do that?

Comment: Are you using Android Studio? If this is your case try using this plugin https://github.com/mcharmas/android-parcelable-intellij-plugin/ this will generate all the boilerplate code for you

Comment: copy to http://parcelabler.com

Comment: Both optiones work fine! Thanks a lot. Unfortunately in class Call i have List of object and there is problem with incompability of List and ArrayList what can i do about that?
 this.roaming = new ArrayList<List<States>>(); in.readList(this.roaming, List<States>.class.getClassLoader());

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parcelable it's really a lot of boilerplate that, coding manually, have a great chance to fall in error.

Use this site: http://www.parcelabler.com/

This tool automatic generate the parcelable fields for your class. Remember to make the Classes declared as class variables to be parcelable too.

The result will be somenthing like this:

```
public class Tariff implements Parcelable {

private String operator;
private Discounts discount;
private boolean unlimited;
private Billings billing;
private String name;
private double price;
private double calculated;
private Call call;
private Sms sms;

    protected Tariff(Parcel in) {
        operator = in.readString();
        discount = (Discounts) in.readValue(Discounts.class.getClassLoader());
        unlimited = in.readByte() != 0x00;
        billing = (Billings) in.readValue(Billings.class.getClassLoader());
        name = in.readString();
        price = in.readDouble();
        calculated = in.readDouble();
        call = (Call) in.readValue(Call.class.getClassLoader());
        sms = (Sms) in.readValue(Sms.class.getClassLoader());
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(operator);
        dest.writeValue(discount);
        dest.writeByte((byte) (unlimited ? 0x01 : 0x00));
        dest.writeValue(billing);
        dest.writeString(name);
        dest.writeDouble(price);
        dest.writeDouble(calculated);
        dest.writeValue(call);
        dest.writeValue(sms);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Tariff> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Tariff>() {
        @Override
        public Tariff createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Tariff(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Tariff[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Tariff[size];
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Both optiones work fine! Thanks a lot. Unfortunately in class Call i have List of object and there is problem with incompability of List and ArrayList what can i do about that?
 this.roaming = new ArrayList<List<States>>();
        in.readList(this.roaming, List<States>.class.getClassLoader());